# SageMaker Studio Notebooks

Tags: csrf, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Do sage maker studio notebooks generate a token whenever it is started? Because I am not able to find the token in .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json. I am actually trying to connect to this jupyter notebook remotely but facing issues..

Answer (score 0):

With SageMaker Studio, you can access the notebook via SageMaker Console.

Review the following to understand more about Access control and SageMaker Studio notebooks
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/security-access-control-studio-nb.html

Not sure, I follow what you refer to as remotely? Perhaps you could elaborate on the specific use case that will require you to have this .json file access.